# Does a safety team get fined if a rocket launch fails due to the safety of the rocket?

Tags: launch, failure, safety

I was writing a story and I wanted to write about this topic but I could not find a straight answer from any website.

Please help

Comment: In what organization? They are structured very differently from each other.

Comment: Usually not. It would introduce too many problems. Read Wayne Hales blog, its really illuminating. the cause of failure often is not because a single person, or a single team, failed. its most often because either some procideure is wrong or because there are organizational deficits. You usually can't blame a single source. And trying to do so would undermine any integrity your teams have. The teams have to work together, not try to shift blame to each other. they need to make sure it doesn't repeat itself, not trying to make sure somone else gets blamed. Rocketry is a very different business.

Comment: I think the worst thing that could happen to a single team member is getting fired for gross negligence. AFAIK it's illegal in many jurisdictions to fine employees for mistakes. But even that would be counter-productive. It would give incentive for people to hide their mistakes, which makes it harder to find the actual reason and prevent it in the future.

Comment: I suggest you read Chapter 7 of the Columbia Accident Investigation Board report to see a real world example of what happened within the safety organizations that allowed the safety system to fail, and the consequences to those organizations. https://www.nasa.gov/columbia/home/CAIB_Vol1.html